# Problems getting spreadsheet grid look with Viewbox and ListView in UWP Project

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a 'spreadsheet like' grid with column headers showing information from a set of player objects with the cell contents maximised in size. To do this I have a UWP app with a `ListView` bound to the collection of `Player` objects. The `ListView.ItemsPanel` uses a `UniformGridPanel` obtained from [here](https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control)

The `UniformGridPanel` has a `Rows` property bound to the player count which can vary, and one Column. The `UniformGridPanel` is used to show ALL players, giving each player item equal height, so no player is partially displayed and there is no scrolling. The `UniformGridPanel` is working fine.

The `ListView.ItemTemplate` is a `Grid`of a fixed number of columns representing data about each player.

My problems are:

1. The info in each 'Cell' is not big enough. I would like each 'cell' content maximised, and the grid layout to remain spreadsheet like, i.e. square, with rows and columns aligned.
2. I don't know how to put Headings on each of the Columns that would align with the cells in each column.

So the display looks like this below. This is the closest to what I want, but for the size of the cell contents and the column headers.

[image: Bad layout]

As you can see there is plenty of room to make the numbers and letters bigger. I've tried many variations using `Viewbox` in the XAML. For example, wrapping the `ListView` in a `Viewbox` produces this which is no good as the columns are misaligned.

[image]

If I put `Viewbox` around each `Border`control that defines a 'cell' I still get problems with the layout too.

I've tagged this post with WPF despite my problem being in a UWP context in case someone has had a similar experience in that domain that could be applied here.

CODE BEHIND:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Player> players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();

        players.Add(new Player("John", "Smith",1,99,11,1));
        players.Add(new Player("Fred", "Blogs", 19, 25, 11, 1));
        players.Add(new Player("Andrew", "Sykes", 19, 25, 11, 2));
        players.Add(new Player("Dean", "Andrews", 19, 179, 11, 1));

        this.DataContext = players;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Grid x:Name="grdPlayers" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!--<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">-->
        <ListView  x:Name="lvwPlayers"
                Padding="0"
                BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="5"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

           
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:UniformGrid x:Name="pnlPlayer" Rows="{Binding Count}" Columns="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>


            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="grdPlayerRow">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Initials}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HighScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Average}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TonCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <!--</Viewbox>-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

PLAYER CODE:

```
public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Player(string firstName, string lastName, int low, int high, int avg, int tonCount)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        LowScore = low;
        HighScore = high;
        Average = avg;
        TonCount = tonCount;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _tonCount;
    public int TonCount
    {
        get { return _tonCount; }
        set
        {
            _tonCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private double _average;
    public double Average
    {
        get { return _average; }
        set
        {
            _average = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _lowScore;
    public int LowScore
    {
        get { return _lowScore; }
        set
        {
            _lowScore = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _highScore;
    public int HighScore
    {
        get { return _highScore; }
        set
        {
            _highScore = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public string FullName
    {
        get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }
    }

    private string _firstName = string.Empty;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Initials");
        }
    }

    private string _lastName = string.Empty;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Initials");
        }
    }

    public string Initials
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FullName;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

@Grace Feng, your answer to use the `lvwPlayers` loaded event before assignment of the DataContext gives the following output which is NOT what I wanted. To begin with the rows are of different heights for no reason??:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Base on your description, I think there is no need to use the `UniformGridPanel`, you can simply customize a `Grid` to make its Height equals its Width. For example, create a `TemplatedControl` like this:

```
public sealed class SquareGrid : Grid
{
    public SquareGrid()
    {
        this.Loaded += SquareGrid_Loaded;
    }

    private void SquareGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height = this.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

And for the question of "I don't know how to put Headings on each of the Columns that would align with the cells in each column.", I think you can set them as the `Header` of `ListView`. But it's very wise of you to use `ViewBox` to make the `Text` fill the size. Here comes the demo:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="900">
    <ListView  x:Name="lvwPlayers"
            Padding="0"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="5"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <!--<ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:UniformGrid x:Name="pnlPlayer" Rows="{Binding Count}" Columns="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>-->
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:SquareGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="Initials" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </local:SquareGrid>
                <local:SquareGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="HighScore" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </local:SquareGrid>
                <local:SquareGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="LowScore" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </local:SquareGrid>
                <local:SquareGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="Average" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </local:SquareGrid>
                <local:SquareGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="4">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="TonCount" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </local:SquareGrid>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grdPlayerRow">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <local:SquareGrid Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Initials}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </local:SquareGrid>
                    <local:SquareGrid Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HighScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </local:SquareGrid>
                    <local:SquareGrid Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </local:SquareGrid>
                    <local:SquareGrid Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Average}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </local:SquareGrid>
                    <local:SquareGrid Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TonCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </local:SquareGrid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Rendering Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, sorry for late reply to your post. Your solution is nearly there but not quite.  The problem with your solution is that when there are many players and the  `ListView` named lvwPlayers is contained within a `Grid` that's within another `Grid` the `ListView` doesn't show all the players. In fact, despite having no scrolling you can click into the `ListView` and using the arrow keys move to the 'hidden' ones. This is not what I wanted. I wanted ALL players to be shown. Can you offer any help with this?

Comment: @Cleve, you mean your `ListView` cannot be scrolled down to show more items? That's because you disable the `ScrollViewer` inside it `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"`, I thought you designed it to be so.

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng , apologies I haven't explained myself well. I don't want the `ListView` to scroll. I would like ALL the players (+Header row) to be  visible straight away in the space allowed by the `ListView` parent. So, irrespective of how many players there they are all still visible immediately. In doing this I accept that the size of the items might scale down to fit the available space.

Comment: @Cleve, if the items count is known before added into `ListView` and no items will be removed or added later, then it is simple. If not, I think you will need to recalculate and re-render your `ListView`, which is nuch more complicated.

Comment: Feng, the Items count is known before adding to `ListView` and no items will be added or removed. Are you able to offer a solution please?

Comment: Sorry you're name keeps getting clipped off for some reason?

Comment: @Cleve, it's OK, you can simply set a `Height` to `ListView` firstly and then add `var itemheight = lvwPlayers.Height / (players.Count + 1);
lvwPlayers.Width = 5 * itemheight;
` before your code `this.DataContext = players;`, in the meanwhile, it is possible that you will also need to modify the style of [ListViewHeaderItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299135.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, that won't work for me. I don't want to set an explicit height for `lvwPlayers`. I need to use the Height given by `lvwPlayers` containing parent. Also, the width shouldn't be fixed as a function of the height. Again (the width) should be that provided by the containing parent. Are you able to help with this?

Comment: @Cleve, since each cells are square, so the width is exactly 5 times of the item's height, am I right?  For the unfixed height problem, you can code in the `Loaded` event of `ListView`: `var itemheight = lvwPlayers.ActualHeight / (players.Count + 1);
lvwPlayers.Width = 5 * itemheight;
`, use its `ActualHeight` property.

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, the cells don't have to be square - just aligned in a grid like formation and showing their content to its biggest size. I don't think your solution will work. All you'll be doing surely is making the `listView` smaller after its rendered? I don't see that it will be making sure ALL the players are shown?

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, please see Update in original post above. It shows the screen shot of your `Loaded` event suggestion which doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: @Cleve, my suggestion works only in the condition using the `SquareGrid` to make each cell be square as you expected at the first time. I know now you want your cell to be rectangle, and now I don't have any clue... sorry.

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, the new screen shot is based on the using the `SquareGrid`. You thinking it was square was perhaps inferred from my use of `UniformGridPanel` in original post, so apologies. I still think something could be done using `ItemsPanelTemplate` similar to original post. But I'm not sure what. What I want to achieve is simple in concept but seems so hard in UWP.